# How to remake BloC and add different states to show CircularProgressIndicator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `BloC` through which I receive data. But I ran into the problem that there are no different states so that I can display the loading indicator and handle errors if there are any. Can you tell me how can I modify this `BloC` class to have different states MyCarsLoading, MyCarLoaded so that I can display the loading indicator in the appropriate state?

**bloc**

```
class MycarsCubit extends Cubit<MycarsState> {
  MycarsCubit()
      : super(MycarsInitial(
          number: '',
          type: '',
        ));

  String number = '';
  String type = '';

  void clear() {
    number = '';
    type = '';
  }

  void change({
    required String numberText,
    required String typeText,
  }) {
    number = numberText;
    type = typeText;
    emit(MycarsInitial(
      number: number,
      type: type,
    ));
  }
}
```

**state**

```
abstract class MycarsState {}
 
class MycarsInitial extends MycarsState {
  String number;
  String type;

  MycarsInitial({
    required this.number,
    required this.type,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this using the `freezed` package with cubit, but without that you could do something like this:

```
class MycarsState extends Equatable {
  final String number;
  final String type;

  const MycarsState._({
    this.number = '',
    this.type = '',
  });

  const MycarsState.initial() : this._();

  const MycarsState.loading() : this._();

  const MycarsState.loaded({required String number, required String type})
    : this._(number: number, type: type);
    
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [number, type];
}
```

Then you can do like this:

```
 void change({
    required String numberText,
    required String typeText,
  }) {
    emit(const MycarsState.loading());

    number = numberText;
    type = typeText;

    emit(MycarsState.loaded(
      number: number,
      type: type,
    ));
  }
```

Comment: and what should I specify in cubit in the super method instead of MycarsInitial?

Comment: `const MycarsState.initial()`

Comment: I don’t understand a little how to access states in the UI, because when I access the state, I am asked for variables that are in the constructor

Comment: @Max, I understand. I think that I have answered this question in a good way, so I think that you should close thjs question by accepting my answer. This question was how to change your current setup to have several other states such as loading etc.. I suggest that you create a new question for the next specific thing, i.e. how to present it in a UI. Otherwise this can go on for ever and ever with just more and more questions :) The idea is to ask small precis questions to get forward :) I'd be happy to help on the next question as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I agree with you, now I'll try)

Comment: Yes, your code does not work in UI, I added a new question if you know how to solve, I will be grateful for your help :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527651/what-is-the-correct-way-to-invoke-bloc-states-in-the-ui

Answer (score 0):

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterweathertutorial?id=weather-state You can see here how it is handled.